# A-Star Algorithm is running like Dijkstra and delivers a wrong result

Tags: java, algorithm, openstreetmap, a-star

I'm trying to implement A-Star in Java based on OSM Data. My problem is that my implementation is not working correctly. First of all the path is not the shortest. Second the closedlist contains more 1/3 more nodes in the end as Dijkstra. Thats actuall not that what I expected.

Here is my A-Star code which is based on [Wikipedia Pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm)

```
public Object[] executeAstar(ArrayList<Arclistentry> data, NodeD start, NodeD dest,long[] nodenur)
{
    openlist = new PriorityQueue<NodeD>(1,comp);
    closedlist.clear();
    openlist.offer(start);
    start.setg(0);
    start.seth(calccost(start, dest));
    start.setf(start.getg()+start.geth());
    while(!openlist.isEmpty())
    {
        NodeD currentnode = openlist.poll();
        if(currentnode.getnodenumber() == dest.getpredessor())
        {
            closedlist.add(currentnode);
            return drawway(closedlist, start, dest);
        }
        closedlist.add(currentnode);
        ArrayList<Arclistentry> entries = neighbors.get((int)currentnode.getnodenumber()-1);
        for(Arclistentry aentry:entries)
        {
            NodeD successor = new NodeD(aentry.getnode(),aentry.getstart(), aentry.getcoorddest());
                float tentative_g = currentnode.getg()+calccost(currentnode,successor);//+aentry.getcost();
                if(contains(successor, closedlist))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if((contains(successor,openlist))&& tentative_g >= aentry.getcost())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                        if(!contains(successor, openlist))
                        {
                            successor.setpredessor(currentnode.getnodenumber());
                            successor.setg(tentative_g);
                            successor.seth(calccost(successor, dest));
                            successor.setf(successor.getg()+successor.geth());
                            openlist.offer(successor);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            openlist.remove(successor);
                            successor.setpredessor(currentnode.getnodenumber());
                            successor.setg(tentative_g);
                            successor.seth(calccost(successor, dest));
                            successor.setf(successor.getg()+successor.geth());
                            openlist.offer(successor);
                        }
        }
    }
    return drawway(closedlist,start, dest);
}
```

My Heuristics will be calculated by using the euclidian distance. But to consider also the cost of the node, the costs are multiplied with the heuristics result. My Data structure contains the following:

```
private long nodenumber;
private long predessor;
private float label;
private float f;
private float g;
private float h;
private double[] coord = new double[2];

public NodeD(long nodenr, long predessor, double[] coor)
{
    this.nodenumber = nodenr;
    this.predessor = predessor;
    this.coord = coor;
}
public NodeD(long nodenr, long predessor, float label)
{
    this.nodenumber = nodenr;
    this.predessor = predessor;
    this.label = label;
}
```

and for the arclist I use the following:

```
private long start;
private long dest_node;
private float cost_;
private double[]coordstart = new double[2];
private double[]coorddest = new double[2];
```

Contains Function for Priority Queue:

```
public boolean contains(NodeD o, PriorityQueue<NodeD> al)
 {
     Iterator<NodeD> e = al.iterator();
     if (o==null)
     {
          while (e.hasNext())
          {
             if (e.next()==null)
             {
                 return true;
             }
          }
     }
     else
     {
         while (e.hasNext())
         {
             NodeD t = e.next();
             if(t.equals(null))
             {
                 return false;
             }
             if (((o.getnodenumber()==t.getnodenumber()) & (o.getpredessor()==t.getpredessor()))||(o.getnodenumber()==t.getpredessor() & o.getpredessor()==t.getnodenumber()))
             {
                 return true;
             }
         }
             return false;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

and contains for ArrayList (because it was not detecting right with the ArrayList.contains function

```
public boolean contains(NodeD o, ArrayList<NodeD> al) {
           return indexOf(o,al) >= 0;
       }

public int indexOf(NodeD o, ArrayList<NodeD> al) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
                if (al.get(i)==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
                   for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
                   {
                      if ((o.getpredessor()==al.get(i).getpredessor())) //(o.getnodenumber()==al.get(i).getnodenumber()) &&
                      {
                           return i;
                      }
                       else if((o.getpredessor()==al.get(i).getnodenumber())&&(o.getnodenumber()==al.get(i).getpredessor()))
                      {
                          return i;
                      }
                   }
               }
        return -1;
}
```

The problem is that the algorithm is visiting all nodes. The other problem is the sorted openlist, which is pushing neighbors of the currentnode up, because they have a lower f value. So what I'm duing wrong by implementing this algorithm?

Comment: `But to consider also the cost of the node, the costs are multiplied with the heuristics result.` This seems fishy. One optimality requirement of A* algorithm is that the heuristic NEVER OVERESTIMATES the cost. If you violate that, (which I suspect you are), then A* no longer guarantees shortest path. There may be issues with your implementation too, but fix your algorithm first.

Comment: That would mean that A-Star is only based on the distance and the cost of the way wouldn't have any influence on the way finding method? That would exclude A-Star always if additional costs for the way have to be considered, if I understood your comment right.

Comment: No, A-star is based on the distance travelled PLUS an estimate of the distance yet to travel, which produces an estimate of the final path via this node. You can't just add multiplicative factors in there. If you do, the path will wrongly be judged as worse than it is, which would explain why you end up exploring more nodes than you really need to.

Comment: So I cannot set my real g as the set costs which I get from OSM2po for every vertex? And my g is then always the real euclidean distance from node to node, where h the estimated bee line is from the current node to the end node?

Comment: `g` is the ACTUAL shortest-path cost from the START to the neighboring node. This is computed exactly. `h` on the other hand, is an ESTIMATE of the cost from the neighbor to the GOAL. `g` must be the actual cost, and `h` must not be higher than the actual cost. Note that Dijkstra is a special case of A* when `h = 0`.

Comment: So I changed now the calculation from g to the actual costs from OSMData. h to the calculated euclidean distance to the goal. The number of investigated nodes is now about 20% lower than by Dijkstra. But I'm not sure if this is that what I want. Because I thought it should be much lower than by Dijkstra.

Comment: And the execution time is still two times higher than the execution time of Dijkstra.

Comment: The better your heuristic is, the better A*-search performs. If there is no very good heuristic A*-search will not perform very well. You may try to search from start and destination at the same time [Bidirectional_search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search).

Comment: @IrgendwPointer: if you've changed the code you're asking about, change the code that is here in this question, or we're just guessing at whatever bugs might exist.

Comment: @Kylotan I changed now the Code in my posting.

Comment: For test purposes I set h for the whole time to 0. Therefore I should get the same result as Dijkstra. But thats not the case. I get 3 times more nodes in my closedlist than Dijkstra. So therefore must be a big error in my source code. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing with the arclist_indx? you seem to use it to get the arcs you need but are you sure it working as expected? Why do you iterate over b=1..currentnode.getnodenumber? nodenur seems to hold the number of neighbours for each node, why are you summing that?

Comment: That was/is to figure out the neighbours from my datastructure. But I'm looking forward to change this right now to an ArrayList which contains the neighbours and where I can easy iterate through.

Comment: if currentnode.getnodenumber gives you the id of the node, then your b-loop makes a sum of the number of neighbours of all nodes with a lower id (lower than the id of currentnode). You're calculating an index into an array, which is very time-consuming.

Comment: This is removed. I'm now iterating through a list. But my Dijkstra was working with the same structure.

Comment: You are creating a new NodeD object ever time you evaluate a link. successor.g is not initialised by your constructor but you compare it to your tentative value. You should also check if your contains function acts as you intended, as it could be checking the hash of your new object instead of its properties.

Comment: Can you explain the part of your code where you decrease the current shortest path value of a node?  This happens when a node is in the open-list but is not the element with smallest path cost in the open list.  As far as I can sees you use the `contains` call a couple of times which can break the time complexity of Dijkstra and A-Star.  Also I don't see you removing the node when its cost decreases; I'm not sure wether this causes any problems.

Comment: If you mean `openlist.poll()` is removing the node from the openlist and investigating it's neighbors. `float tentative_g = currentnode.getg()+aentry.getcost();` is calculating the current costs. It is taking the previous costs and the costs from the current node to it's neighbor. This value will be set to the successor as new g value. What would be an alternative to `contains`? I don't remove nodes from the `closedlist`. Only from the `openlist` in the first line after the while loop started. As you can see the `openlist` is `PriorityQueue` and therefore it is sorted automatically.

Comment: Just was testing the costs of both Algorithm: Dijkstra has the same total costs as A* in the end. But the estimated heuristics factor h at the beginning is almost the half of the total costs. Therefore estimation is quiet lower than the real costs. Is this correct? If yes, then the estimation is done correctly and there is another problem with my algorithm.

Comment: I would second @Origin's question about your `contains` function. Nobody's suggesting an alternative to it, just to make sure it does exactly what is intended, ie. to compare against equivalent nodes, which may not be happening with a simple equality check. Your current algorithm allows you to add a node to the open even if it also exists in the closed list when the new score is better, which raises a red flag over how you do the comparisons.

Comment: Still think you should look at the contains function. I think the closedlist will contain multiple NodeD objects referring to the same physical node, so could you check if that's the case?
I'm also thinking you should adjust your checks. If a successor belongs to your closed list, you can continue. Same thing for the tentative distance, if it's larger just continue. Those 2 conditions should be || instead of &&. That should speed it up as well.

Comment: I was thinking about your comments and I figured out, that the code in the english wikipedia is wrong. Therefore I took the code from the german wikipedia. Now I receive 1/3 of the nodes which Dijkstra is finding. The runtime is 1/3 lower than Dijkstra. But I'm still not sure if I did it right. So I posted my contains methods as well. So you can go through and maybe there is still an error, which I didn't spot yet. Generally what I do in contains is to compare source and dest and vice versa if it is already in of those lists. If yes then return true, if not return false.

Comment: The used pseudocode is now: [http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*-Algorithmus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*-Algorithmus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recap of all our previous answers:

- Make sure the A* estimation is a lower estimate otherwise it will wrongly skip parts
- Do not iterate over all nodes to determine the index of the edges of your current node's edge set in an array
- When creating new objects to put in your queue/sets, checks should be done on the properties of the nodes
- If your focus is on speed, avoid as much work as possible by aborting non-interesting searches as soon as possible

I'm still unsure about this line:

`if((contains(successor,openlist))&& tentative_g >= aentry.getcost())`

What I think you are trying to do is to avoid adding a new node to the queue when you already have a better value for it in there. However, tentative_g is the length of the path from your starting node to your current node while aentry.getcost seems to be the length of the edge you are relaxing. That doesn't seem right to me... Try to retrieve the correct (old) value to compare against your new tentative label.

Lastly, for your current code, I would also make the following changes:

- Use HashSet for your closedlist. Every time you check if a node is in there, you have to go over them all, which is not that efficient... Try using a HashSet by overriding the hash function of your NodeD objects. The built-in contains-function is much faster than your current approach. A similar argument can be made for your openlist. You cannot change the PQ to a set but you could omit the contains-checks. If you add a node with a bad priority, you will always first poll the correct priority (because it PQ) and could then, when polling the bad priority, just skip it. That's a small optimisation that trades off size of PQ to PQ lookup-operations
- avoid recalculating stuff (mainly calccost()) by calculating it once and reusing the value when you need it (small time gain but nicer code).
- try to avoid multiple lines with the same code by placing them on the correct line (e.g. 2 closedlist.add function can be merged to 1 add-call placed above the if condition, if you have something like if(..){doA();doB()}else{doA();doC();} try to put doA() before the if for legibility)